# Unknown input size cin

Tags: c++, input, cin

I'm sure this is a simple issue. It should honestly be the easiest part of writing a SAT solver, but, I'm supposed to have the user input data like this:

```
Sample Input:
1              <-- 1st number denotes the number of cases I will have
5              <-- 2nd number represents the number of variables, followed 
1 2 3              who knows how many clauses.
-1 3 4
-2 -3 5
-5 -1 2
-4 1 -2
-4 -1 -2 -3 -5

*blank line separates the different cases*
.... followed by as many cases as the user said they had
```

So, I'm storing these clauses into string vectors, and they're all going into another vector. So what would be the best way to get this input from the user? The fact that the amount of clauses isn't initially given is the part that is mostly confusing me. I would try a while()... But I don't know how to terminate it. I guess I'm a bit unsure of how cin will work in this situation.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why are there six 'variables'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two separate problems: (a) read an unknown number of lines of input and (b) parse a given line of input into an unknown amount of `int`s.

First, reading lines from input. That's just [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

```
std::string str
while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    // ???
}
```

Then, given `str`, we have to parse it into `int`s. The simplest way is to put it into a [stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::istringstream iss(str);
```

And then either read `int`s one by one:

```
int i;
while (iss >> i) {
    // do something
}
```

Or put all of them into a `vector` at once by passing it a pair of [`istream_iterator<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>{iss},
                   std::istream_iterator<int>{}};
```

So a complete example that logs the sum of each line of input would be:

```
std::string str
while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::vector<int> v{std::istream_iterator<int>{iss},
                       std::istream_iterator<int>{}};

    if (!v.empty()) {
        std::cout << "sum=" << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is very common for homework and contest questions, and the answer looks like this:

```
#include <sstream> //you may not have known about this

int num_cases = 0;
std::cin >> num_cases;
for(int case_num=0; case_num<num_cases; ++case_num) { //for each case       
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> variables;
    int num_variables = 0;
    std::cin >> num_variables;
    std::cin.ignore(1); //ignore the newline character, it messes with getline
    for(int var=0; var<num_variables; ++var) { //for each variable
        std::string linestr;
        std::getline(std::cin, linestr, '\n'); //read whole line into string
        std::istringstream linestream(linestr); //make a stream from the line

        int newclause = 0;
        std::vector<int> lineclauses;
        while(linestream >> newclause) //for each clause
            lineclauses.push_back(newclause); //add it to the row
        //when that fails, we read the whole line
        variables.push_back(lineclauses); //so add the row to 'variables'
    }
    //Do stuff with variables vector.
}
```

Comment: Hm. If  I understand the OP correctly, the number of clauses is unknown?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: Right, The first line is the number of cases.  Each case begins with a line containing the number of 'variables'.  Each 'variable' is a line with an unknown number of 'clauses'.  That's why we have to grab the whole line via `getline` into a `istringstream` and loop through that until it's empty.  I added comments for clarity.

Comment: I am not familiar with this fomat (although I have seen it pop up in questions here); but in the example given, there are 6 lines following the 5. An oversight?

Comment: Reading about `getline()` I understand that it reads (and discards) the newline; why the cin.ignore()`?

Comment: @PeterSchneider: oh, you're right, it's `>>` that leaves the newlines.  I've moved the ignore.  You're right that there are six lines following 5 in the sample, I have no explanation for that.